# UIBezierPath with multiples arcs

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uibezierpath

Hiiii

I'm trying to draw in a view an arc with dynamic width. 
[image]

I have built an ARRAY with several UIBezierPath with arcs then I draw one after the other. this is the code:

```
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
    // Drawing code

    CGFloat radious;
    if (self.bounds.size.width < self.bounds.size.height) {
        radious = self.bounds.size.width / 2;
    }
    else{
        radious = self.bounds.size.height / 2;
    }

    float oneGradeInRadians = (float)(2 * M_PI) / 360.f;
    float radiandToDraw = (float)self.finalAngleRadians - self.initialAngleRadians;
    float splitMeasure = oneGradeInRadians;
    int numberOfArcs = radiandToDraw / splitMeasure;

    NSMutableArray *arrayOfBeziersPaths = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numberOfArcs];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfArcs; i++) {

         float startAngle = self.initialAngleRadians + (i * splitMeasure);
         float endAngle = self.initialAngleRadians +((i + 1) * splitMeasure);
         UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2) radius:radious - self.widthLine.floatValue startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:YES];
        bezierPath.lineWidth = self.widthLine.floatValue + i/20;
        float hue = (float)(i / 3.f);
        UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue/360.0 saturation:1 brightness:1 alpha:1];
        [color setStroke];

        [arrayOfBeziersPaths addObject:bezierPath];
    }



    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinMiter);
    //We saved the context
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfArcs; i++) {
        [(UIBezierPath *)[arrayOfBeziersPaths objectAtIndex:i] stroke];
        [(UIBezierPath *)[arrayOfBeziersPaths objectAtIndex:i] fill];
     }

    //Restore the contex
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }
```

In this way I get the right shape but, also I get an annoying lines between the arcs:
[image]

I think the problem may be a property to change between arcs, but I'm totally lost, or maybe there is another better way to build this.

I tried creating several UIBezierPath paths and I added them to an unique UIBezierPath, then I stoke and fill that path. I didn't get the annoying lines, but the problem is I can not modify the line width, so I can not get the same effect.

Any idea? thanks

Answer (score 4):

dont create many such paths. just create `two arcs (inner circle, exterior circle)` and `two straight` lines joining the ends. then fill the path.

Add below code in a viewDidLoad of an empty viewController and check.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGFloat k =0.5522847498;
    UIBezierPath *path =[UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    CGFloat radius=130;
    [path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(0, 0) radius:radius startAngle:M_PI_2 endAngle:M_PI clockwise:NO];

    CGFloat start=10;
    CGFloat increment=5;
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(-radius-start, 0)];
    [path addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, -radius-start-increment) controlPoint1:CGPointMake(-radius-start, -(radius +start)*k) controlPoint2:CGPointMake(-(radius+start)*k, -radius-start-increment)];
    [path addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(radius+start+2*increment, 0) controlPoint1:CGPointMake((radius+start+increment)*k, -radius-start-increment) controlPoint2:CGPointMake(radius+start+2*increment, (-radius-start-increment)*k)];
    [path addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, radius+start+3*increment) controlPoint1:CGPointMake(radius+start+2*increment, (radius+start+2*increment)*k) controlPoint2:CGPointMake((radius+start+2*increment)*k,radius+start+3*increment)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0,radius)];

    CAShapeLayer *layer =[CAShapeLayer layer];
    [layer setFrame:CGRectMake(150, 200, 300, 300)];
    [layer setFillColor:[UIColor greenColor].CGColor];
    [layer setStrokeColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
    [layer setPath:path.CGPath];
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];
}
```

It produced result like,
[image]

Comment: This is an amazing approximation and very useful but My problem is I want the user increments or decrements that draw, in clockwise way. It's not the solution, but you gave to me a great way to find out it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you’ve chosen a crazy approach to drawing the shape you’re after.  If you take a look at it, you’ll see that it’s actually a filled region bounded on the outside by a circular arc, and on the inner edge by a spiral.

What you should do, therefore, is create a single `NSBezierPath`, add the outer circular arc to it, then add a line to the start of your spiral, append a spiral (you’ll want to approximate it with Bézier segments) and finally call `-closePath`.  After that, you can `-fill` the path and you’ll get a good looking result rather than the mess you have above.